# how can i create a video duration bar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how can i create a video duration bar so that if i add a video in listbox the duration bar should automatically increas its total duration and display the duration on it....just like in any video editing software...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a `ProgressBar` or a `TrackBar`.